# Java Generic Doubly Linked List Swap

Tags: java, pointers, generics, swap, doubly-linked-list

http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~weiss/dsaajava3/code/MyLinkedList.java

Above link shows the code that I want to modify in order to have swap method from the doubly linked list. I apologize in advance using URL in place due being 300 line of code pasted here is not very readable.

For the output, I'd like to just have a single list **output, for example**:

```
[ 28 27 **21** 25 24 23 22 **26** 20 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ]  //(2, 7) swap
```

**Below is my attempt (part of the code to include/modify to original)**:

*swap method:*

```
public AnyType swap( int idx, int idx2)
{
    return swap( getNode( idx ), getNode ( idx2 ) );
}

private AnyType swap( Node<AnyType> p, Node<AnyType> p2)
{
    Node<AnyType> temp = p;   //realize it doesn't work due to linking
    p = p2;
    p2 = temp;

    return p.data;
}
```

*main:*

```
class TestLinkedList
{
  public static void main( String [ ] args )
  {
    MyLinkedList<Integer> lst = new MyLinkedList<>( );

    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
            lst.add( i );
    for( int i = 20; i < 30; i++ )
            lst.add( 0, i );

    lst.remove( 0 );
    lst.remove( lst.size( ) - 1 );

    lst.swap(2, 7);
    System.out.println("swap: " + lst);
  }
}
```

*output*

```
swap: [ 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ]
21
```

I realize that my approach to solution is not the use of linked list. I've been analyzing the code that I am to modify; however am having hard time with the pointers and the doubly linked list to understand the coding part (not the concept). Please explain how I should approach to solution. Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
/* Swaps idx and idx2 nodes
 * @param idx the index of the object
 * @param idx2 the index of the object
 */
public void swap( int idx, int idx2)
{
    swap( getNode( idx  ), getNode ( idx2 ) );
            if( idx < 0 || idx >= size( ) || idx2 < 0 || idx2 >= size( )){
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException( "swap first index: " + idx + ", second index: " + idx2 );
    }
}

/**
 * Swaps node and data at p and p2
 * @param p the index of the object
 * @param p2 the index of the object
 */
public void swap( Node<AnyType> p, Node<AnyType> p2)
{

    Node<AnyType> temp = p;
    p = p2;
    p2 = temp;

   temp = p.next.prev;
    p.next.prev = p2.next.prev;
    p2.next.prev = temp;        


    AnyType dataTemp = p.data;
    p.data = p2. data;
    p2.data = dataTemp;
}
```

*output*

```
[ 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]
swap: [ 29 28 22 26 25 24 23 27 21 20 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]
```

It is now working. Did I do it right? However I get compile error with. I assume it has to do with `public void swap( Node<AnyType> p, Node<AnyType> p2)` method which has `warning: exporting non-public type through public API`. What can I do here to fix it?

Comment: It's a doubly linked list.  Please think carefully about what needs to happen.

Comment: Draw the linked list on paper, like shown on the [Doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) Wikipedia page. Then update your drawing to do what you want. Once you understand how it should work, you're ready to code it. Make sure you cover how it works if first and/or last element is begin swapped, or if the two elements are direct neighbors. --- One think for sure: Updating the parameter references in your method will do nothing to the list at all. And why does `swap` have a return value?

Comment: @Andreas, I did what you said (I think). Could you take a look?

Comment: To fix compiler warning, make the method private. What is point of swapping the p and p2 reference? Drop the first 3 lines, they are meaningless. Swapping `.next.prev` is just 1 of 4 pointer pairs that need swapping, if you want to swap nodes. You could just swap the `data` as you do and be done with it, so just keep the last 3 lines and that's it. However, if this is an exercise in doubly linked list manipulation, then drop those last 3 lines, and write the rest of the code to swap the rest of the pointer pairs, i.e. `.prev.next`, `.prev` and `.next`, taking care to handle first/last node.

Comment: @Andreas, Thank you the warning for that method is gone. Yes I want to swap nodes. So other 3 of 4 would be: .prev.next, beginMarker, and endMarker? I'm still getting compiler warning errors, though I do get correct output.

Comment: Only in the fringe case of swapping first and last. See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your input is:

`[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]`

and you want to swap 3 and 7:

`[ 1 2 >7< 4 5 6 >3< 8 9 ]`

This means you need to update all these values:

```
2.next = 7
7.prev = 2
7.next = 4
4.prev = 7
6.next = 3
3.prev = 6
3.next = 8
8.prev = 3
```

That is a total of 8 assignments, not counting assignment to temporary variables.

---

What if you wanted to swap 5 and 6 instead:

`[ 1 2 3 4 >6< >5< 7 8 9 ]`

```
4.next = 6
6.prev = 4
6.next = 5
5.prev = 6
5.next = 7
7.prev = 5
```

Hmmm... That was only 6 assignments.

---

What if you wanted to swap first and last element:

`[ >9< 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 >1< ]`

You didn't share this part, but I'll assume you have both a head and a tail reference, so:

```
head   = 9
9.prev = null
9.next = 2
2.prev = 9
8.next = 1
1.prev = 8
1.next = null
tail   = 1
```

Whoa, that was different.

---

Now you just need to code all that, taking care to handle all combinations.